# Convert xml datetime data using xslt 2.0 to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:ff

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt

I am using xslt 2.0 to format xml datetime data to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:ff.

***xml:***

```
<TODAYDATE>2019-03-28T17:59:49.963-08:00</TODAYDATE>
```

***xslt 2.0:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(TODAYDATE, '[Y,4]-[M,2]-[D,2] [h01]:[m]:[s]:[f][PN,2-2]')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

***Expected result:***

2019-03-28 17:59:49:96

***XSLT Fiddle:***

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiT

Comment: Did you do a typo for the milliseconds decimal separator?

Comment: @ggmath, My bad corrected the original post

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to limit the fractions of seconds to 2 decimal places? How to remove the AM/PM indicator (which I doubt you want to do)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Yes, That's correct. 24 hour hour format and limit the fractions of seconds to 2 decimal places without the AM/PM indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
format-dateTime(TODAYDATE, '[Y]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]:[m01]:[s01]:[f01]')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(TODAYDATE, '[Y]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]:[m01]:[s01]:[f01]')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why are you repeating my answer.